# Count document satisfies criteria in MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Below one of the document inside my `test.users` collection.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62ef8c502935226353a97efb"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    {
      "$oid": "62ef8c722935227aaca97eff"
    }
  ],
  "emailConfirmed": true,
  "ipInfo": {
    "ip": "191.23.43.218",    
    "region": "Krasnodarskiy",
    "country": "RU",    
    "timezone": "Europe/Moscow"
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

I want to count the number of `country` of `RU` in `test.users` collection in MongoDB compass, how should I do it? I only saw `filter`, `project`, `sort`, `collation` under Documents as follows in Mongo DB compass, is there a way I can directly enter a mongoDB query?
[image]

Comment: `"ipInfo.country": "RU"` under filter should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, but I hope to return the count @nimrodserok

Comment: You can use the `Aggregations` tab and enter your pipeline there: `"$match"` and then `"$count"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mongosh` shell present below, or you can directly check the count below `FIND` button after running your query, text is like `Displaying document x of y`:

[image]

[image]